# How to remove first part of every line?

Tags: perl, parsing, delimiter

Say I have a text file that is of the format:

```
S1:I am line one.
S2:I am line two.
S3:I am line three.
S4:I am line four.
```

How can I remove the ID part of each line (so that I'm only left with `I am line one.` and so on)? Is it better to change the input record separator `$/` or use a regex that removes ID?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Like this perhaps? It uses a regex that matches everything up to and including the first colon `:` and removes it

```
perl -pe 's/^[^:]*://' myfile > newfile
```

Within a program:

```
open my $fh, '<', $filename or die qq{Unable to open "$filename" for input: $!};

while ( <$fh> ) {

    s/^[^:]*://;

    # Use remainder of line left in $_
}
```

Comment: I'm doing this within a script, and not on the command line. Will that regex work within the `split` function, like Pablo suggested?